# Razor Pages textarea input just grows and grows when other input validations fail validation

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm using asp.net core and razor pages. I have a simple form page with several textboxes and then 1 textarea. If my model object variable that is linked to the textarea passes validation , but say 1 of the other textboxes fails validation then after the Page returns the value in my textarea grows based on the previous value. so for example if the textarea contained "abc,xyz" then what happens after the Page returns from a failed validation from another regular textbox on the page, then the textarea grows to "abc,xyzabc,xyz"

all i have is a simple textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" asp-for="MyObject.EmailsList" rows="3" placeholder="Multiple addresses need to be seperated by a semi-colon ;"></textarea>
```

I debugged and validated that MyObject.EmailsList only contains "abc,xyz" every time the page returns due to some other textbox validation failing. so i'm scratching my head as to why this textarea is not clearing itself and loading in the value properly??

Answer (score 0):

When you have an input box validation error, you want to double the given value on your textarea, you can refer to this demo:

Model:

```
[Required]
        [BindProperty]
        public string name { get; set; } 
        [BindProperty]
        public myObject MyObject { get; set; } = new myObject { EmailsList="xyz"};
        public  class myObject
        {
            public  string  EmailsList { get; set; }
        }
```

View:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="MyObject.EmailsList" rows="3" placeholder="Multiple addresses need to be seperated by a semi-colon ;"></textarea>
</form>
<button onclick="Test()">click me!</button>


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function Test() {
            $("#myform").validate();
            if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '',
                    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                    data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                })
            } else{
                $("#MyObject_EmailsList").val($("#MyObject_EmailsList").val() + $("#MyObject_EmailsList").val());
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Request:

[image]